# Pull in random form for testing

Tags: php, jquery

I would like some help in starting this project, some advice on where to look. On one of my sites we have a jQuery Tools powered overlay that holds a contact form. The form is located in the /forms directory. I would like to create several (5-6) forms that have different layouts and test which works best with our users.

I think that creating a "control" file in php, and linking to it instead of directly to a form to pull in a random form would work.

I am not sure about the code, but know that I need to:
- read the directory with opendir and readdir?
- add FILES to an array (use is_dir )
- generate a random number between 0 and the count() of the array
- include the specified random file.
- call this function on the click event of the link either inline or jQuery

Would I do this in a separate file? Any advice is much appreciated. Let me know if I need to clarify or add more details.

Thank you.

Comment: "I would like some help in starting this project, some advice on where to look." & "I am not sure about the code" pls take time to read question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you definitely have the right idea. This should be about right, almost exactly as you outlined it. Unless you have a need to load this up with jQuery after initial page load, I'd recommend doing it in the PHP during initial page load.

*adapted from [`readdir()`, example 2](http://php.net/readdir)*:

```
// load random form
$fileList = array();
if ($handle = opendir('./forms')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $fileList[] = $file;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

$randIndex = array_rand($fileList);
include './forms/' . $fileList[$randIndex];
```

> Note: This code assumes that the
>   *forms* directory only contains form files and no other files or
>   directories that need to be excluded.

Also, if you need to capture the file's output in a string rather than print it directly to the browser, see [`include`, example 6](http://php.net/include).